# Save Post doesn't output anything on page

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is the code am using to create custom metabox on WordPress, the Metabox shows fine but when I save the post it doesn't dump the values into the page. It should dump the values from this function "**product_meta_box_save**", which is telling WordPress to fire off on Page Save.

```
<?php
// Little function to return a custom field value
function product_get_custom_field( $value ) {
    global $post;
}

// Register the Metabox
function product_add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'about-products-', __( 'About the Product'), 'product_meta_box_output', 'products', 'normal', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'product_add_custom_meta_box' );

// Output the Metabox
function product_meta_box_output( $post ){
?>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="18%"><?php _e("Product Price (FJD)"); ?></td>
      <td width="82%"><input type="text" size="20" name="product_price"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php _e("Product Stock"); ?></td>
      <td><input type="number" size="50" name="product_stock"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?php }

// Save the Metabox values
function product_meta_box_save( $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    var_dump( $post );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'product_meta_box_save' );
```

Comment: it wont...i cant remember the reason why its either a redirect or the function is initiated by ajax in the admin section..you can grab the information on page load though

Comment: @David Thanks, now I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as David said it uses ajax to save the post so it won't ever show you that data.

Instead you should do something like this with the save function:

```
function product_meta_box_save( $post_id ) 
{
       if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )  
       {
           return; //this prevents it from saving the values during its autosaves
       }

       if ( $_POST && isset($_POST['metabox_data'] ) ) 
       {
           update_post_meta($post_id, 'metabox_data', $_POST['metabox_data'] );
       }
}
```

And this way the data will save and as David said you can dump it out then and do whatever you want with it.